# How to use date variable for getSheetByName?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a simple button on a GGL sheet dashboard to jump to another sheet with the current date in their names (Go to today) and in the format of "mmmm d", such as "July 24".

I almost have no knowledge about this so of course the script do not work, and I think because the variable is not compatible with getSheetByName? Here's the current script:

```
function totodaysheet() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "mmmm d");
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(date), true);
};
```

Would you be able to advise on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- If you want to use the date format like `July 24`, I think that `mmmm d` should be `MMMM d`.
- If the sheet name is not found, an error occurs.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function totodaysheet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMMM d");
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(date);
  if (!sheet) return
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(sheet, true);
}
```

#### Note:

- For example, if today is July 1, 2022, `MMMM d` returns `July 1`. If you want to retrieve `July 01`, please use `MMMM dd`.

#### References:

- [formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)
- [Date and Time Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: It works! Thank you Tanaike for the script and comment :)

Comment: @Extracheesepopcorn Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.